# How to remove similar elements from beginnign of each line in a text file using sed or similar?

Tags: linux, sed

I have text like this:

```
UgxJam3R6oHGHJMrbHx4AaABAg,,hqJGuSXaWcY,UCkhUJbKZIZsARJx7UsX7nw,NAME,https://URLYOUDONTNEEDTOSEE,2023-03-03T22:45:53,Sometextineed,1,false,0,
```

and I want to use `sed` or something to remove and make it like this:

```
https:/blablabl.com/UCkhUJbKZIZsARJx7UsX7nw,NAME,2023-03-03T22:46:53,Sometextineed
```

```
*,,*, replaced with url
```

I'm new to using Linux in general but I don't get how `sed` works. I tried stuff.

Pls give me solution that I can just copy and paste.

Ok I have file with (random,,random,) times 10000 and i need to remove that. All the lines have the same structure.

Comment: You want to read from file or what?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Unfortunately your question is very unclear. Please see [how to formulate a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help), then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771934/edit) your question so that it's clear what exactly you need. Please don't answer questions in comments, but also edit the original question so it gets more focused, stays up-to-date and relevant info is readily available. When editing please enclose textual output in code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting.

Comment: Another thing to note: you should include examples of "stuff" you tried, and what results they produced. Not understanding `sed` isn't unusual, it's a very powerful tool - O'Reilly's "sed & awk" has ~450 pages...

Comment: Is the structure the same in all lines - `random characters` `2 commas` `random characters` `single comma`? Please confirm in the question.

Comment: yes peregrino they are all in same manner

Comment: Please do edit the question - I did now for you. It's really confusing trying to get a full picture of the situation when one needs to dig through multiple comment threads.

Comment: @Peregrino69 first time asking a question soory i will be better next time maybe but i thought it was clear i needed it for a file

Comment: Everyone has a first time, friend :-) I suspected you need it for a file as otherwise the question makes little sense. But the fact is that the other members of the community know exactly what you tell them, nothing more. The devil's in the details - the more you give, the better the answers can be.

Comment: @Peregrino69 can you close this and marked as solved and tell me how to do that

Comment: ... you really should check the Help :-D The only one who can mark a post "Resolved" is the original poster, in this case you. The way to do that is to [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) the helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash simply use this:

```
mystring=UgxJam3R6oHGHJMrbHx4AaABAg,,hqJGuSXaWcY,UCkhUJbKZIZsARJx7UsX7nw,NAME,https://URLYOUDONTNEEDTOSEE,2023-03-03T22:45:53,Sometextineed,1,false,0,
IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$mystring"
echo "https://blablabl.com/${EX[3]},${EX[4]},${EX[6]},${EX[7]}"
```

`mystring` in first line is your string

I you want to do this in a file just run this command:

```
sed -i "s/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),.*$/https:\/\/blablabl.com\/\4,\5,\7,\8/" /tmp/mytest.txt
```

`/tmp/mytest.txt` at the end of the command is the file name

Comment: Does this work only with the given string, or is this applicable if the number or order of elements delimited with `,` is different, or the URL is different? The OP hardly needs a `sed` solution just to strip off elements from a single string. How does this work if the strings to replace are read from a file?

Comment: look, there should be something to detect the part you need! in the only example you provided it can be done just by order!

Comment: Also there is an empty part which shows it has order. just test it, if worked accept the answer please. if didn't elaborate you question!

Comment: Friend, did you notice I'm not the OP asking the question? :-) I agree, there needs to be something to identify the part to be replaced. But the question as is is very vague, methinks OP needs to update it to clarify what exactly their need is.

Comment: How am i going to do that to a file with 10k lines with random,,random,

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice! :) actually you're right but usually they can't ask clear question! I answer them and if it works, I edit their question myself to clarify!

Comment: that my friend should be in question body!

Comment: Updated the answer, please accept if it was helpful!

Comment: @RastkoVukovic test the second part!